# Unable to parse "Not" sign in Haskell in a expression

Tags: parsing, haskell

I want to make a parser in Haskell that parses boolean expresionns from logic. I am stuck at a point. The parser I use is unable to parse "Not" sign unless is at the front of a expression.

This works:

```
parse exprparser "" "~x^y|-z"
```

but this doesn't:

```
parse exprparse "" "x^y|-~y"
```

It doesn't parse anything after the not (`"~"`) sign. How can I fix this?
This is the code I am working on:

```
exprparser :: Parser Expr
exprparser = buildExpressionParser table term <?> "expression"
table = [ [Prefix (m_reservedOp "~" >> return (Uno Not))]
    , [Infix (m_reservedOp "," >> return (Duo Virgula)) AssocLeft] 
    , [Infix (m_reservedOp "&" >> return (Duo And)) AssocLeft]
    , [Infix (m_reservedOp "^" >> return (Duo Or)) AssocLeft]
    , [Infix (m_reservedOp "|-" >> return (Duo Dem)) AssocLeft]
    ]
term = m_parens exprparser
   <|> fmap Var m_identifier
   <|> (m_reserved "true" >> return (Con True))
   <|> (m_reserved "false" >> return (Con False))
```

Comment: What is the `Parser` type? Is that from `Parsec`, `megaparsec`, `attoparsec`, or maybe something custom?

Comment: parser. But i already solved it. Thanks

Comment: Parsec, you mean? Write your solution in an answer here for points.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isn't enough information and it's already solved by the asker.